# systemd-cryptsetup key file readable warning

Tags: systemd, encryption, disk-encryption

Ok, so I've been debugging the last update of my system and found this warning running `journalctl -b -p warning`:

`systemd-cryptsetup: Key file <location> is world-readable. This is not a good idea!`

Generally I understand what is the matter and that it's bad. Though I don't know how to fix this properly without ruining my boot.

Then comes the question: what permissions do I have to set for that file to make  my system working correctly while removing the warning? Is `600` ok? Or do some system groups also need an access to this file?

Comment: Some quick googling around suggests that `600` is a good permission set for the keyfile.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I also think so but posted here to make sure It's indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so indeed `600` permissions are considered a good and the only good practice for securing a key file (source: [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Device_encryption)).

Also the tricky thing here is that when the kernel is updated `initramfs` generation procedure resets the key file permission to `644` which basically allows to dump it's content.

That means that after each kernel update the right permission set should be restored by user.